# A curious output after an arithmetic operation in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I was trying out basic arithmetic operations in GNU Octave to try and see the kind of error it would bring.This is the error that I was expecting

```
error: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2 is 3x1)
```

And so I tried adding the row vector `b = [1,2,3]` to the column vector `c = [1;2;3]` and to my SUPRISE! an output came forth.

How can this be?

```
octave:59> b
b =

   1   2   3

octave:60> c
c =

   1
   2
   3

octave:61> b + c
ans =

   2   3   4
   3   4   5
   4   5   6
```

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html) it'll be explained.

Comment: Looks like [broadcasting](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Broadcasting.html).